# how to split txt file into two lists and than split one list to its captions

Tags: python, pandas

Got this text file:

```
1e.jpg#0   A dog going for a walk .
2e.jpg#1   A boy is going to swim 
3e.jpg#2   A girl is chasing the cat .
4e.jpg#3   Three people are going to a hockey game
```

I need to split it into two separate lists. One list for IDs and the second for the sentences.
This is where I need help as now I need to split the sentences list into the following:

```
[["a", "dog", "going", "for", "a"...], ["a",......]]
```

This is how far I got

```
path = "s.txt"

l1 = []
l2 = []
read_file=open(path, "r")
split = [line.strip() for line in read_file]
for line in split:
    l1.append(line.split("\t")[0])
    l2.append(line.split("\t")[1:])
    
print(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same principle. The `split` function splits on whitespace by default. I also removed the `:` from `l2.append(line.split("\t")[1:])` so that it returns a string instead of a list with one element:

```
path = "s.txt"

l1 = []
l2 = []
read_file=open(path, "r")
split = [line.strip() for line in read_file]
for line in split:
    l1.append(line.split("\t")[0])
    l2.append(line.split("\t")[1])
    
words_list = []
for s in l2:
    words_list.append(s.split())

print(words_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about punctuation being added to your lists, you can just split your string in your current code (assuming only one tab character occurs):

```
l1 = []
l2 = []
read_file=open(path, "r")
split = [line.strip() for line in read_file]
for line in split:
    l1.append(line.split("\t")[0])
    l2.append(line.split("\t")[1].split())
    
print(l2)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'dog', 'going', 'for', 'a', 'walk', '.'], ['A', 'boy', 'is', 'going', 'to', 'swim'], ['A', 'girl', 'is', 'chasing', 'the', 'cat', '.'], ['Three', 'people', 'are', 'going', 'to', 'a', 'hockey', 'game']]
```

If you want to remove non-word elements, you can use `re.split`:

```
import re
split_pattern = re.compile(r'\W? \W?')

l1 = []
l2 = []
read_file=open(path, "r")
split = [line.strip() for line in read_file]
for line in split:
    l1.append(line.split("\t")[0])
    word_list = [x for x in re.split(split_pattern, line.split("\t")[1]) if x]
    l2.append(word_list)
    
print(l2)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'dog', 'going', 'for', 'a', 'walk'], ['A', 'boy', 'is', 'going', 'to', 'swim'], ['A', 'girl', 'is', 'chasing', 'the', 'cat'], ['Three', 'people', 'are', 'going', 'to', 'a', 'hockey', 'game']]
```